# How Do I Jump To The Point In The Channel Where The Chat Is Found?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Chatting with someone in Teams end up with a very long history.

When I use the search function it shows me the message that matches the search term but even when I click on it I am only shown that specific chat message.

Generally speaking, when I am searching for a chat message I want to see the conversation around that search term and not just a single chat message.

How do I jump to the point in the chat history that the search message was found so I can read the discussion around that message?

Comment: Stack Overflow is generally only for programming-related questions, so please note your question might be downvoted or even closed as it's not of that sort. I've answered below in any case, hopefully it's of help.

Comment: I thought so too but I couldn't find any other stackexchange site and this tag was here